# Как сделать плавную смену css градиента при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, hover

Как можно сделать плавную смену фона (градиент на градиент) при наведении `hover` на элемент. Сделал кнопку, дал ей все необходимые стили, включая `transition` для плавности эффекта наведения, но при этом смена фона происходит резко, а все остальные эффекты в виде изменения тени, как положено меняются плавно.

```css
.btn_default {
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 200px;
 font-family: $bold;
 font-size: 1.125em;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 13px 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 outline: none;
 border-radius: 30px;
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(158, 48, 160), rgb(213, 80, 298));
 box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(213, 80, 208, 0.6);
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.btn_default:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(101, 31, 102), rgb(173, 65, 169));
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(213, 80, 208, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn_default">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
.btn_default {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    font-family: $bold;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(158, 48, 160), rgb(213, 80, 298));
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(213, 80, 208, 0.6);
    position: relative;
}
.btn_default > span{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn_default:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(101, 31, 102), rgb(173, 65, 169));
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(213, 80, 208, 0.9);
    border-radius: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.btn_default:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn_default"><span>Some link</span></a>
```

Comment: А как нибудь менее геморно не выйдет? Я так понял что transition никак не влияет на градиент?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.btn_default {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .8);
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: hsla(294, 53%, 47%, 1);
  box-shadow: inset .125em .125em .5em hsla(294, 53%, 40%, 1), inset -.125em -.125em .5em hsla(294, 53%, 40%, 1), 0 2px 7px rgba(213, 80, 208, 0.6);
  transition: all .8s linear 0s;
}

.btn_default:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: hsla(294, 53%, 37%, 1);
  box-shadow: inset .125em .125em .5em hsla(294, 53%, 30%, 1), inset -.125em -.125em .5em hsla(294, 53%, 30%, 1), 0 2px 10px rgba(213, 80, 208, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn_default">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.button--primary{
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  transition: 2s;
  z-index: 1;

  &::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: inherit;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: @gradient;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  &::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: inherit;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: @gradient-hover;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &:hover::after{
    transition: inherit;
    opacity: 100;
  }
}
```